# Adding dynamic script to avoid browser caching not working in IE v.11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am trying to add a script file with a random token at the end of the src attr in order to avoid browser caching for that file.

the code i have added is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/UserPlans.js/?v=" + (Math.random() * (99999 - 10000) + 10000) + "'><\/script>");</script>
```

this works fine when testing with chrome but doesn't work on IE 11.
when glancing the network details in the IE developer tool i see that it tries to download the script file with `type: text/html` where the type should be `application/x-javascript`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. 
I forgot to use escape characters and also no need to add a slash before the parameter.

The weird thing about it was that chrome knows how to fix the link so it worked...